# Post-increment of array value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I learned what the different between post-increment and pre-increment was, but still surprised by the below code:

```js
let array = [1];
array = [array[0]++];
console.log(array);
```

I expected `array[0]` would be returned on the right hand first, then `array` would be assigned as `[1]`. After that, `array[0]++` would be executed, and `array` should be `[2]`.

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: You *overwrite* `array`. Assignments are right to left - the right side resolves to `[1]` and that's what you assign to `array`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [1]; 

let item = array[0]++; // item = 1

array = [item]; // array = [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As we see in C++

```
int  x= 2;
cout<< x++ ;
```

Just like in C++, the control first sets/prints the value and then increment it. It is the same case here.

```js
let array = [1];
array = [array[0]++];
console.log(array);
```

However, You can use the following below code to see difference

```js
let array = [1];      //array[0]=1
array = [++array[0]]; //array[0]=2
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-increment** means that the variable is incremented before the expression is set or evaluated. **Post-increment** means that the expression is set or evaluated and then the variable is changed. It is a two-step process. Here is your example:

```js
// post increment
arr = [1];
console.log('A:', [arr[0]++] ); // the same like: y = x;
// 1

// pre increment
arr = [1];
console.log('B', [++arr[0]]); // the same like: x++; y = x;
// 2

// and now to understand what the diffenrence

arr = [1];
// post increment
console.log('C1', [arr[0]++] ); 
// pre increment
console.log('C2', [++arr[0]] );
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple definition for this issue

```js
let array = [1];
array = [array[0]++];
console.log(array);
```

The above statement is a post increment operator. So the value will be incremented only once the operation is completed. Post increment make use of `use and update` methedology. Your value will be used frst and will be updated only after that. You updated `array[0]` but overwrote `array` with `[array[0]++]`. So its make use of current value for assigining to `array` Since you overwrote `array`, ther is no significance for update operator.

The post increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing.

So the value for `array` is overwritten with `[array[0]++]`. This will first assign `[array[0]++]` to your array and increment `array[0]`. So `[1]` will be assigned to `array`.

Comment: "*This will first assign [array[0]++] to your array and increment array[0]*" no, that's not how it works. The right-hand expression is evaluated *before* the assignment happens.

Comment: No, it happens after the retrieval of the value. Post increment does retrieve -> increment, pre-increment will do increment -> retrieve. In both cases it's an atomic operation. If it worked *after* the line was finished, then `x = 0; y = x++ + x++;` would assign `0` to `y`. However, the result is `1` because the first `x++` *does* increment the value so the second `x++` would return `1` and increment a second time.

Comment: Yes @VLAZ same im telling. Post increment does retrieve -> increment operation. So at the time of execution of `array = [array[0]++];`, the value for the right hand side is 1. This will be incremented only after that statement execution. To be more specificc, its a `use and update` mechanism. But the user overwrote `array` with `[array[0]++]` So the update opratation has anything to be done here.

Comment: You said that the assignment happens before the increment. That's not the order of operations - it's increment first, and only afterwards is the value assigned to `array`.

Comment: It not the assignment, its the usage of the variable. if its _it's increment first, and only afterwards is the value assigned to array_ then why the value is not updated in array?

Comment: Because `array[0]` returns `1` and then increments the value. The original array is now `[2]`  but this value is irrelevant. `[array[0]++]` produces the value `[1]` which gets assigned to `array` and this overwrites the previous value which was `[2]` . Again, if post increment worked *after* the assignment had done then `x = 0; y = x++ + x++;` would result in zero. It does not. Therefore, increment happens after the retrieval of the value, before the expression finishes fully evaluating. It ends up evaluating as `0 + 1` and at the end of that (before assignment to `y`) `x` is already `2`.

Comment: @VLAZ this is not how post increment works. _If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing._ There is no overwriting. The value is returned before the expression is evaluated. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: If that's not how it works, then explain why `x = 0; y = x++ + x++;` results in `y = 1` and not `y = 0`.

Comment: `x = 0; y = x++ + x++;` => its a sequential execution the first `x++` is evaluated first. First its takes value 0, again it executes `x++`. Now the value for `x` is `1` hence `y = 0 + 1 = 1`

Comment: Correct. This is exactly how it works with `[array[0]++]` - the `array[0]++` is evaluated first, it produces `1` and increments the value in the array to `2`. Next it creates a new array with the return value of `array[0]++`, which is `[1]`. It's sequential. *AFTER* that happens, the assignment is done `array = [1]`. This wipes away the array with incremented value in it. Again, sequential.

Comment: This is the dsame thing that I mentioned in the answer. how post increment works.